# How to convert nested object to query string in Angularjs

Tags: arrays, angularjs, nested, query-string

I want to convert this object:

```
$scope.foo =  {
    bar: {
        baz: 'foobarbaz'
    }
}
```

to

```
foo[bar][baz]=foobarbaz
```

query string.

Also how to convert

```
$scope.fields = ['id', 'name', 'created_at']
```

to

```
fields[]=id&fields[]=name&fields[]=created_at`
```

Is there any library or function in Angularjs to do this job?

Comment: I don't think AngularJS has built in function for that. Why don't you write your own.

Comment: how to write this function? can you help me?

Comment: I don't know any AngularJS library that can do this, but I think you can do it yourself easily :)

Comment: thanks @Mistalis, what should I do? do you have any sample code?

Comment: @Yogesh I see [qs](https://github.com/ljharb/qs) library to this job, but I don't know it possible use in angularjs or no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to write those serializers yourself, Angular has the one built-in for you. imply inject [$httpParamSerializerJQLike](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike) service and use it:

```
$scope.foo = {
  foo: {
    bar: {
      baz: 'foobarbaz'
    }
  }
};

$scope.fields = {
  fields: ['id', 'name', 'created_at']
};

console.log( $httpParamSerializerJQLike($scope.foo) );
// => "foo[bar][baz]=foobarbaz"

console.log( $httpParamSerializerJQLike($scope.fields) );
// => "fields[]=id&fields[]=name&fields[]=created_at"

// (output shown URL-decoded)
```

Comment: in console log show me: `5B%5D=id&%5B%5D=name&%5B%5D=created_at` . how to see in correct view

Comment: This is correct view, it's url encoded, how it's supposed to be. If you need to decode it use decodeUriComponent function.

Comment: Thanks solve it, but another error on the console: `Error: filter:notarray
Not an array` and `Expected array but received: {"fields":["id","name","created_at"]}`

Comment: we put this code in function and when ng-click event fired this code ran

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this

```js
function toPhpQuery(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
    var val = obj[key];
    var prefix = encodeURIComponent(key);
    return Array.isArray(val) 
      ? _toPhpQueryArray(val, prefix)
      : _toPhpQueryObject(val, prefix);
  }).join("&");
  
  function _toPhpQueryArray(arr, prefix) {
    return arr.map(v => prefix + "[]=" + encodeURIComponent(v)).join("&");
  }

  function _toPhpQueryObject(value, prefix) {
    if (typeof value === "object" && value) {
      return Object.keys(value).map(k => _toPhpQueryObject(value[k], prefix + "[" + encodeURIComponent(k) + "]")).join("&");
    } else {
      return prefix + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
    }
  }
}


console.log(toPhpQuery({
  foo: {
    bar: {
      baz: 'foobarbaz'
    }
  },
  fields: ['id', 'name', 'created_at']
}));
```